# Webpack sass-loader with sourcemap and devtool

Tags: webpack, sass-loader

Hey I'm new to Webpack.

I searching a solution for switching between dev and prod mode via a cmd argument for sourcemaps.

Webpack comes native with

```
webpack --devtool eval
```

But this command is ignored by the sass-loader (https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader)

According to the description on the sass-loader page it's nessercery to write the options for the sourcemaps fix in the config file:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Is there any solution to make this configurable via the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) which requires node-sass and webpack as peerdependencies and resolve this issue by using the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin)

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    ...
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],
};
```

Check out [test/sourceMap](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/tree/master/test) for a working example. Hope this helps!